# How to add characteristics to a service

Tags: swift, swift3, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an Peripheral in Bluetooth Low Energy technology.

I have a service and I want to add (Set) a characteristic for it, the [current documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH4-SW1) states that we can just assign an array of CBCharacteristics to the characteristics object of the CBService (CBMutalbeService) object. However, now the characteristic property is a read-only property.

So this won't work

```
cBService!.characteristics = [cBCharacteristic1]
```

#### My question

How can I set my characteristics?

#### Attempts

1. Looking to the constructor, there's just one and it does not provide a way to set it.
2. I couldn't find any method to set that value
3. Google wasn't my friend in this search so far

Best,

Comment: What do you mean won't work? How did you create `cBCharacteristic1` and how did you create `cBService`? Did you create `CBMutableService` and `CBMutableCharacteristic` and not `CBService` and `CBCharacteristic`?

Comment: @Larme as I stated *However, now the characteristic property is a read-only property.* can you infer what kind of error I got from that line? cBCharacteristic1 is an object of CBMutableCharacteristic class, it was created using its **only** initializer (constructor) that accepts its UUID, properties, permission and value. And yes CBMutableService and CBMutableCharacteristic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

I was creating the service like this:

```
var cBService : CBService?
```

While I should have created it like this:

```
var cBService : CBMutableService?
```